# Conditionally change field widget type with Drupal hook_form_alter

Tags: widget, drupal-8, hook-form-alter

I want to conditionally change the widget of a plain text field attached to a node by using hook_form_alter in Drupal 8.7.6.

```
function mymodule_form_node_article_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $options=[
    'test1'  => 'AAA',
    'test2'  => 'BBB',
    'test3'  => 'CCC',
    'test4'  => 'DDD',
  ];
  $form['field_testdrop']['widget'][0]['#type']='select';
  $form['field_testdrop']['widget'][0]['#options'] = $options;

}
```

However, when trying to save the node, I get the following error:

Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::setValue() (line 155 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/NestedArray.php).

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: This is a classic example of an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Works:

```
    $form['field_priority_email_id']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['field_priority_email_id']['widget'][0]['value']['#options'] = $options;
    $form['field_priority_email_id']['widget'][0]['value']['#size'] = NULL;
```

You have to set '#size'  to NULL or the select widget will not render correctly.

Comment: This is wrong, you can't presume the field widget is anchored at the root. You need to use the appropriate field widget alter hooks https://www.drupal.org/node/3180429 since 9.2.0 it is `hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter` (but the answer was wrong for any D8 and later).